# Which CSS identifier is used for the selected tab in tabbed tables in browsers other than IE?

Tags: css, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

When you have a table on a form in Notes, you can choose to display only one row at a time (via the Special Table Row Display parameter on the Table Rows tab of the Table properties).

In a Notes document displayed using Internet Explorer that contains such a table, a row is displayed with a cell for each "tab". The TD that serves as the tab for the selected "Notes table row" is assigned `<td class="dominoSelTopTab">`, while the other tabs get `<td class="dominoTopTab">`.

However, when using other browsers, it's not nearly as simple.

In Firefox, each "tab" ends up as a single-celled-single-row-table within the table with very little to identify it.

```
<td><table border="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr><td><div align="center"><b>Tab 2</b></div></td></tr>
</table></td>
```

A non-selected tab would show as follows:

```
<td><table border="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr><td><div align="center"><a name="1." href="/Projects/MyCSS.nsf/0c3b9489476440c085257a62006d97d6/d482a1767a4af77f85257a62006db064?OpenDocument&amp;TableRow=1.0#1." target="_self">Tab 1</a></div></td></tr>
</table></td>
```

So, the question is, how do I identify the selected tabs and the non-selected tabs when not using IE?

Note: For those who are not Notes developers, the HTML is auto-generated from the visual design as laid out in the Notes designer client. I would replace it all with manual HTML, except there is so much of it that doing so would consume far too much time.

Comment: What version of Domino is generating the HTML?  And what versions of IE and Firefox. To be honest, I didn't know that Domino's HTML generation took browser types into account.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz, Domino 8.5.3, IE 8, Firefox 15.0.1 (I had no idea they'd gone past 5 yet!) I was utterly surprised that there was a difference, so assumed when I saw it in IE that we didn't see it elsewhere.

Comment: Wow.  Varying the HTML generation according to browser type is something I've never heard of Domino doing.  I wonder whether the version of Firefox is just "too new" and some file on the Domino server just needs to be updated to tell it what capabilities it understands. @SimonO'Doherty knows.